# Can I use Windows 7 Professional Product Key to activate Windows Home Basic?

Tags: windows-7, product-key

I have Windows 7 Professional Product key, but I want to install Windows 7 Home Basic, so my question is can I use Windows 7 Professional Product key to activate Windows 7 Home Basic? If no, then how can I downgrade to Windows 7 Home Basic? You answer will be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd not just use Windows 7 Professional? It gives you everything Home Basic does, plus other things which you can easily ignore if you want.

Comment: I have an old pc to install windows on, I don't want aero desktop, no bitlocker just basic lightweight windows 7 which can run smoothly.

Comment: Those features are there but they can be deactivated (if they're supported at all). The only real difference for the Home version is less files on your HDD/SSD. Actual performance should be identical (e.g. Bitlocker isn't active unless you turn it on).

Comment: To improve performance, press Win+R to bring up the "Run" dialog, paste in `%windir%\system32\SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe` and click on OK. Then select "Adjust for best performance" and click on OK. That will disable aero plus a number of other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with all the comments regarding the 'why' nonetheless if you want to try, you can use **Windows 7 Downgrader**

This, however, requires that you install Windows 7 Enterprise edition **then** downgrade to Home Premium

Run the program on Windows 7 Enterprise edition and select the version you want to downgrade to. Next, insert your Windows installation disk, select 'Upgrade' and your Windows 7 Enterprise will be downgraded to the version you have specified.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/downgrade-windows-7-enterprise-to-ultimate-professional-or-home-premium-edition/

No mention of reentering key so I assume it is not required

Comment: Doesn't work. Enterprise itself must be activated first, before you can downgrade. Activation requires a key.

Comment: OP "I have Windows 7 Professional Product key"

Comment: Yes, but that isn't an Enterprise key. Enterprise needs a KMS license server for its key or a special key for non-KMS activation. Only after Enterprise is activated can you "upgrade" to an arbitrary "downgrade" version.